# How to include multiple conditions in if statement inside a while loop?

Tags: r

In my dataset ([link to the csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y_tdUbzXKUTq9NoPDOixNTgGVZbD8GHR/view?usp=sharing)), each consecutive 6 rows (starting from the beginning) is considered a block, i.e., 3 '+1' ramp values and 3 '-1' ramp values. I want to remove any such block that has an  'acc_list' value of '0' or '-1', keeping only those blocks with all 6 'ramp' values as 1.
I'm trying this loop but it's not working. Can you please help me with where I am going wrong?

```
i <- 1
while (i < 3241){
  if (data$acc_list[data$count == i] != 1  || data$acc_list[data$count == i+1] != 1 || data$acc_list[data$count == i+2] != 1 || data$acc_list[data$count == i+3] != 1 || data$acc_list[data$count == i+4] != 1 || data$acc_list[data$count == i+5] != 1){
    data <- data[-c(i, i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5), ]
  }
  i <- i + 6
}
```

Comment: Google drives is blocked at work so I can't see your data. I'd suggest using group_by() and filter() instead of a for loop.

Comment: Do you want to ignore or skip these cases while reading in?

Comment: Hi! Actually, I want to remove such blocks(6 rows) which has one or more 0 or -1 acc_list values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your task correctly you might be able to work this with just a few lines. Unfortunately I am not sure what you mean by all ramp values equal to 1 as you said each block consist of 3 times 1 and 3 times -1 so maybe you need to do further filtering. As far as removing the blocks with any acc_list value beeing 0 or -1 you can use this code:

```
library(tidyverse)

dt <- readr::read_csv("path_to_your_file/data_cleaned_27.csv")

dt %>%
  # use row numbers and integer devision to get group ids (have to subtract 1 from the row_number as 6/6 is 1 but should be in group 0)
  dplyr::mutate(rn = (dplyr::row_number()-1) %/% 6) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(rn) %>%
  # filter those groups where all value of acc_list are different then 0 or -1
  dplyr::filter(all(!acc_list %in% c(0, -1))) %>%
  # always ungroup grouped data
  dplyr::ungroup()



      X1 count  p_id  ramp coh_list acc_list rt_data    rn
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     7     7     1     1    0.175        1   0.771     1
 2     8     8     1     1    0.25         1   0.542     1
 3     9     9     1     1    0.325        1   0.773     1
 4    10    10     1    -1    0.325        1   0.709     1
 5    11    11     1    -1    0.25         1   0.730     1
 6    12    12     1    -1    0.175        1   0.650     1
 7    13    13     1     1    0.175        1   0.632     2
 8    14    14     1     1    0.25         1   0.540     2
 9    15    15     1     1    0.325        1   0.486     2
10    16    16     1    -1    0.325        1   0.552     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your data, you can use `rle` to find viable blocks of usable data. This will be something of a descent into indexing hell, so it is useful to remind ourselves what is indexing what:

```
dim(data)
[1] 3240    7
```

Usable blocks are length 6L of which there are:

```
> 3240/6
[1] 540
```

Make some row numbers (begin and end) for these blocks:

```
begin_540 <- seq(1,3240,6)
end_540 <- begin_540 + 5
```

Make an empty list outside of our for loop to receive values:

```
blocks_lst <- list()
for (j in 1:length(begin_540)) {
blocks_lst[[j]] <- rle(data$acc_list[begin_540[j]:end_540[j]])$lengths[1]
}
```

If the first value of $lengths is 6, it is a good block. This part of the logic is fragile, as it assumes there are no runs of either -1 or 0 that are 6 or longer, which, as it happens, is not the case in you present data, but to be kept in mind. Index the good blocks:

```
good_blocks_idx <- which(unlist(blocks_lst) == 6)
```

We'll use `good_blocks_idx` to index `begin_540` and `end_540`. and we'll make a copy of data to receive our good blocks.

```
data_2 <- data
data_2[1:nrow(data_2), ] <- NA
head(data_2, n = 2)
   X count p_id ramp coh_list acc_list rt_data
1 NA    NA   NA   NA       NA       NA      NA
2 NA    NA   NA   NA       NA       NA      NA
```

We'll remove the NA rows with `na.omit` at the end. Now we'll simplify our index(s) by combining begin/end and good_block_idx
that will leave us with start and end rows of good blocks.

```
start <- begin_540[good_blocks_idx]
end <- end_540[good_blocks_idx]

for (j in 1:length(start)) {
data_2[start[j]:end[j], ] <- data[start[j]:end[j], ]
}

data_2 <- na.omit(data_2)
dim(data_2)
[1] 1242    7
1242/6
[1] 207
length(start)
[1] 207
 # percent blocks good
length(start)/length(begin_540)
[1] 0.3833333
```

There are far cooler ways (which don't immediately come to mind), but these base tools are very useful to be familiar with. HTH